# vba - new sheets from columns, paste column A if X in column X to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Looking to generate a new sheet for each column in a workbook. (done, pasted below). Next step is to paste the value of Column A if a value is in column 'X'.

```
Name | Email | Course 101 | Course 203 |
John | john @|      X     |      X     |
Jane |Jane@  |      X     |            |
```

Result would be two sheets, (Course 101, Course 203) controlled with a 'Range' function during the sheet generation code.

Part I'm stuck on, is how to paste John's name on the Course 101 and Course 203 sheet and Jane only on the Course 101 sheet.

Here's the code that works for the sheet generation (I think found on here :) )

```
Sub AddSheets()
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim wsWithSheetNames As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wbToAddSheetsTo As Excel.Workbook

    Set wsWithSheetNames = ActiveSheet
Set wbToAddSheetsTo = ActiveWorkbook
For Each cell In wsWithSheetNames.Range("A1:d1")    
    With wbToAddSheetsTo
        .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
          Debug.Print cell.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    Next cell
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above will work to insert the worksheets but it does not do anything after that. Based off the script above I wrote up something similar that does what you want but with slightly easier to understand variables and terms.
The code pasted below requires you to enter the main worksheet name or just set the main worksheet's name to "Main".

This code should be a lot easier to understand since it breaks the process up into 2 blocks.

```
Sub FillCourseWorksheets()
  Dim wb As Workbook, cws As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, found As Boolean
  Dim crw As Long, rw As Long, col As Integer, wsName As String
  Dim CheckString As String, student As String, lastRow As Long
  Dim lastCol As Integer, courseName As String, resultRow As Long

  'this code depends on the main sheet to have the headers in row 1

  '----------------------------------------------------------
  wsName = "Main" 'set this to the name of your main worksheet
  '----------------------------------------------------------


  'set up
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  'if you get an error here set the sheet name to main
  Set cws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
  'use the .end to find the last column and row similar to CTRL + Right/Down
  lastRow = cws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
  lastCol = cws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

  'go through each column and add a worksheet if needed

  For col = 3 To lastCol
    CheckString = cws.Cells(1, col).Value
    'check if the worksheet already exists
     found = False
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
      If ws.Name = CheckString Then
        found = True
        Exit For
      End If
    Next ws
    If found = False Then 'didnt find the sheet. Add it to the workbook
      Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)) 'add the worksheet
      ws.Name = CheckString 'name it
      ws.Range("A1").Value = "Name"
      cws.Activate 'activate the main page after insert
    End If
  Next col

  'all worksheets added go through columns again and add data to each worksheet
  For col = 3 To lastCol
    courseName = cws.Cells(1, col).Value
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(courseName) 'identify the worksheet to use
    For checkrow = 2 To lastRow
      If cws.Cells(checkrow, col).Value <> "" Then
        student = cws.Range("A" & checkrow).Value
        'set the resultrow and check if there is no data
        If ws.Range("A2").Value = "" Then
          resultRow = 2
        Else
          resultRow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & resultRow).Value = student 'print out the student
      End If
    Next checkrow
  Next col


  MsgBox "done"



End Sub
```

Save your workbook before running this and let me know if you have any trouble.